# Sobolev functions counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $A=(0,1)^{d}$.Does anyone have a simple example of a funtion in $H_0^1(A)\cap H^2(A)$ that is not in $H^2_0(A)$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At least for $d=1$, you can take any function $f \in C^2 (\Bbb{R})$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, but $f'(0) \neq 0$ or $f'(1) \neq 0$.

Comment: I cannot quite understand why we only need to look at the first derivative instead of the second @PhoemueX. Assuming I had to prove the same exercise but with all (top) indices increased by $1$, would I then have to find a function with second non-vanishing derivative?
Sorry for bothering you but I think to have misunderstood the "look" of $H_0^k$ spaces

Comment: At least in dimension one, the sobolev spaces can be imagined essentially as follows: The highest derivative can be arbitrarily bad (any $L^p$ function), but the lower derivatives are given by integration of the next higher derivative, e.g. $f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\, dt$. In particular, this means $W^{k,p}\hookrightarrow C^{k-1}$ (at least on bounded intervals). Now, this implies that any function $f \in W_0^{k,p}$ has to have vanishing derivatives up to order $k-1$ on the boundary. The reverse is also true, but not as easy to see.

Comment: In higher dimensions, things are similar, but more complicated (it gets more expensive to trade derivatives against integrability, I.e. to get embeddings $W^{k,p}\hookrightarrow C^\ell$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PhoemueX already said, you need a function, which has zero boundary values, but the derivative is non-zero at the boundary.

In particular, you can take
$$
u(x) = \prod_{i=1}^d x_i \, (1-x_i).
$$
Then, it is easy to see that $u(x) = 0$ for $x \in \partial[(0,1)^d]$, but $\nabla u(x) \ne 0$ for $x \in \partial[(0,1)^d]$. Since $u$ is smooth on $[0,1]^d$, it belongs to $H^2 \cap H_0^1$, but not to $H_0^2$.

**Edit:**
Let me briefly describe that the above properties imply that $u$ does not belong to $H_0^2((0,1)^d)$, albeit $\Omega := (0,1)^d$ has only a Lipschitz boundary.

To the contrary, assume that $u \in H_0^2(\Omega)$. By definition, there exists a sequence $u_n \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^2(\Omega)$. The trace operator $T$ maps $H^1(\Omega)$ continuously into $L^2(\partial\Omega)$. Hence, $0 = T(\nabla u_n) \to T(\nabla u)$ in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$. This is a contradiction to $\nabla u \ne 0$ on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: To apply the characterization used by @PhoemueX for $d>1$, shouldn't $\partial A$ be of class $C^2$?

Comment: No, you don't need $C^2$, Lipschitz boundary is sufficient. A function in $H^1$ belongs to $H_0^1$ iff the trace is zero. And a function in $H^2$ belongs to $H_0^2$ iff the traces of the function and its gradient are zero.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is fine! Another way to do it (more elaborate), is to consider the function $f(x)=\operatorname {d}(x,\partial A)$ and then regularize it.

Comment: @gerw In some books ([Evans](http://tinyurl.com/nfjhdkm), [Adams](http://tinyurl.com/pysbo7y), [Brezis](http://tinyurl.com/nhlcrl8)), smooth boundary is supposed to prove this characterization (class $C^m$ for $W^{m,p}$). Is there any reference that proves it for Lipschitz boundary?

Comment: @Pedro: See the edit. Actually, it is not a characterization of $H_0^2$.